# Why aren’t my Personal Keywords accepted by the registration system in Journal of Number Theory (Elsevier)?

Tags: elsevier, keywords, pre-registration

I have tried many times to register (pre registration) in [Journal of Number Theory](https://www.editorialmanager.com/jnth/default2.aspx) of Elsevier publisher, when I put my Personal Keywords I got the below attached error notice, I separated my keywords by semicolons then by comma, however they asked for 5 keywords, I plugged the required keywords but always the same notice error:

> "You did not enter the required number of Keywords".
>
> "Please use the button below to go back to the Previous Page and enter the missing information":

[image].

I checked the [Author guide](https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/31622/c/10526/supporthub/publishing/) for pre registration  but unfortunately no talking about that personal keywords:

[image]

Comment: Sorry if it's a stupid question, but what even are personal keywords in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like keywords are entered separately, one at a time in a form, not as a list, comma separated or otherwise.

See: [Keyword Instructions](https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/28457/supporthub/publishing/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNjYzNjE4MDM0L2dlbi8xNjYzNjE4MDM0L3NpZC9mVXY4V293a3Jrd3lORDdYTFludnhfb0RjZF9udXZ2ejZ0RTdvTkdiVEFVQ1FROWlyQVhjUDQ4QnZnOFpFVVRzZ3FQViU3RUtIQVlRUGJITHZXOCU3RTUzT0xZTjhIWVJ2Mjk5R1dnNWJYWVdocTNvYVkzSElrT3FvR0VRJTIxJTIx/).

If you entered a long list in the form's box it got confused and sees only one entry.

Comment: And generally need to be spelled properly as well...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help  it fixed now

Comment: @JonCuster Actually it may be better for you to mis-spell keywords. I think they are only used to suggest you automatically to editors as a referee, so by mis-spelling them you get asked to review papers less often. (Source: just speculation.)